# use regex to make sure something contains separate digits

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to scrape locations of companies on websites. I have this function:

```
x=['174 WEST 4TH ST, NYC','All contents © Copyright 2018 Propela']

import re

def is_location(text):
    """Does text contain digits, lowercase and uppercase letters"""
    return all(re.search(pattern, text) for pattern in ['\d{3,16}', '[a-z]*', '[A-Z]'])
# x[1]
# is_location(x[2])

print(list(filter(is_location, x)))
```

I wanted to use regex and somehow only catch things if digits are mentions twice, so since in **174 WEST 4TH ST, NYC** there is a group of digits `174` and then another separate digit `4`.

is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean? i put a sample in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern to match two numbers occurring in separate words in the string:

```
\d+.*\s+.*\d+
```

Here is a sample code:

```
line = "174 WEST 4TH ST, NYC";

res = re.search( r'\d+.*\s+.*\d+', line, re.M|re.I)
if res:
    print "found a match: ", res.group()
else:
    print "no match"
```

Comment: what is re.M|re.I

Comment: It enables boundary markers, and also makes the search case insensitive.  You may add/remove them if you want.

Comment: can I just add  r'\d+.*\s+.*\d+' to my function and get rid of the digit I already have?

Comment: @Bob I don't understand.  What are you trying to do?